# What is the good way of writing Cucumber Framework

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, cucumber

I am new to Cucumber and I am designing the framework.What is the good way of writing framework.

As of now I have designed the framework like this (Page Object Model)

```
Feature File
Given User is on home screen

Step Definition file
@Given("^User is on home screen$")
public void User_is_on_home_screen(String Username,String Pwd)
{
     lp.enterDetails(Username,Pwd)
}

Page related java files (Includes all Methods by page wise,which is called by respective step definition files).    
public class login{
/**
Locators
**/
public void enterDetails(String Username,String Pwd){      
/**
steps
**/
}
```

My question is Can we include the methods in the respective page definition file instead of creating separate java file and store all page locators in one java file

```
Feature File
Given User is on home screen

Step Definition file
@Given("^User is on home screen$")
public void User_is_on_home_screen(String Username,String Pwd)
{
 public void enterDetails(String Username,String Pwd){      
/**
steps
**/ 
}

Page Locators java file (Includes all page locators
public class Locators{
     /**
  All Locators
**/
}
```

Which one is standard and efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use dependency injection in the cucumber and inject page object classes to you step definition using dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

That would look like that:

```
public class BaseStep {

    private DeviceServiceImpl deviceService;
    private DashboardScreen dashboardScreen;
    public BaseStep() {
        this.deviceService = new DeviceServiceImpl(Hooks.driver);
        this.dashboardScreen = new DashboardScreen(Hooks.driver);
    }

    @Then("^I install application$")
    public void iInstallApplication() {
        dashboardScreen.scroll();
    }

    @Given("^I enable all network activity$")
    public void iEnableAllNetworkActivity() {

    }
}
```

In that time you have located all elements on the pages:

```
/**
 * @author Tomash Gombosh
 */
public class DashboardScreen extends AbstractScreen {
    private static final AppElement SIGN_IN_BUTTON = new AppElement(
            "Sign in button",
            By.id(String.format("%s:%s", ApplicationProperties.ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE, "id/right_link")),
            ScrollTo.NO,
            true);
    private static final AppElement SIGN_UP_BUTTON = new AppElement(
            "Sign Up Button",
            By.id(String.format("%s:%s", ApplicationProperties.ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE, "id/sign_button")),
            ScrollTo.NO,
            true);

    public DashboardScreen(final AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayed() {
        waitToBeVisible(SIGN_IN_BUTTON);
        scrollService.scrollDown();
        return allRequiredElementDisplayed();
    }

    public void tapLogin() {
        isDisplayed();
        tap(SIGN_IN_BUTTON);
    }

    public void tapSignIn() {
        tap(SIGN_UP_BUTTON);
    }

    public void scroll() {
        scrollService.scrollDown();
    }
}
```

Would that helpful for you? Or need more explanation?

Comment: Yes I have done the some.But my question is which way is more easy to maintain code and which one is more standard.I have mentioned 2 ways of writing code in my question.

Comment: The first one with methods of the test will be more maintainability because you have separate logic of the application and logic of your tests. And only reuse methods it in the step definitions. Because some of the step definitions can use 3-4 methods from the page object class. And if you will write it in the step definitions you will have a huge and hard to maintainability class.